# snackbar dynamic color change angular 7

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Material Snackbar's colour not getting changed

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackbarService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }
  show(message: string, type?: string, duration?: any) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, type, {
      duration: duration ? duration : 2000,
      panelClass: [type],
    });
  }
}
```

this this the invocation, =>  `this.snack.show(response.message, "success", 3000)`

css Class,

```
.info {
    background: #2196F3;
}
.success {
    background: #1DE9B6;
}
.error {
    background: #B00020;
}
```

but none of the css classes get applied to any Snakbar the appears

Comment: console the `type`

Comment: getting the type :0

Comment: Have you solved this? The class you place in panelClass doesn't get added to the element or it is added but has no effect? These are different issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `::ng-deep` when writing classes .info .success .error

Also try using `background-color` instead of `background` in CSS

Corrected Code

```css
::ng-deep .info {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
::ng-deep .success {
    background-color: #1DE9B6;
}
::ng-deep .error {
    background-color: #B00020;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the class name for `panelClass`. `type` returning `0` will not work

```
  panelClass: ['info'],
```

Comment: i have tried that also but still there is not applying any css

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `encapsulation` property of Component to `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your_selector',
  templateUrl: 'url',
  styleUrls: ['css_file'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  <-- This need to set to override the default CSS
})
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anzddh)

Comment: its not the physical as it can affect some component where i don't need `encapsulation`

Comment: Hmm! Have a look at [documentation](https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/) and [official one](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) the use as per your requirement!

Answer (score 1):

try to edit your css like that in style.scss:

```
.mat-snack-bar-container.success {
    background: #1DE9B6;!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, looks like it's overridden by other top-level CSS files, so the solutions are

- add your classes in `styles.scss` file.
- or if your classes in your component.scss add `/deep/` in front of your classes like:

  `/deep/ .info { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
openSnackBar(message: string) {
 panelClass: ['ghiles-snackbar'],
}


in style.scss
.ghiles-snackbar {
    background: #2196F3;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

my takeoff for the dynamic snackBar function ( I added dynamic positioning ):

```
  public openSnackBar(
msg: string,
type: string, 
durationInSec?: number,
horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'start',
verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition ='bottom',
): void {  // Pop up msg with parameters
if (durationInSec) durationInSec = durationInSec * 1000;
this._snackBar.open(msg, 'X', {
  horizontalPosition,
  verticalPosition,
  panelClass: [type],
  duration: durationInSec
});
```

}